# Hölder's theorem on gamma function

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, gamma-function

I was reading the proof of Hölder's theorem on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20H%C3%B6lder%27s%20theorem%20states,proofs%20have%20subsequently%20been%20found.&text=%2Dgamma%20function.) that the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ does not satisfy any differential equation of form $P(z;\Gamma(z),\Gamma'(z),...,\Gamma^{(n)}(z))=0$, where $P(X;Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is a polynomial (I don't know why there is a semicolon, but see the last paragraph). One of the key idea is to define a total order on monomials, and therefore we may talk about the highest term or "degree" of a polynomial. However the article is kind of vague about that. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order#Examples) there are several orders on monomials. **Which of them is being used here?** More specifically, in the wiki article the following example is given:

$\deg \left(-3 X^{10} Y_{0}^{2} Y_{1}^{4} + i X^{2}Y_{2} \right) < \deg \left( 2 X Y_{0}^{3} - Y_{1}^{4} \right)$

Below is part of the proof.

> Furthermore, if $X^{h} Y_{0}^{h_{0}} Y_{1}^{h_{1}} \cdots Y_{n}^{h_{n}}$ is the highest-degree monomial term in $P$, then the highest-degree monomial term in $Q\stackrel{\text{df}}{=} ~ P(X + 1;X Y_{0},X Y_{1} + Y_{0},X Y_{2} + 2 Y_{1},\ldots,X Y_{n} + n Y_{n - 1})$ is
>
> $X^{h + h_{0} + h_{1} + \cdots + h_{n}}Y_{0}^{h_{0}}Y_{1}^{h_{1}} \cdots Y_{n}^{h_{n}}$.
>
> Consequently, the polynomial
>
> $Q - X^{h_{0} + h_{1} + \cdots + h_{n}} P$
>
> has a smaller overall degree than $P$.

I think for the argument to work we should use the lexicographic order $Y_n<Y_n-1<...<Y_0<X$, i.e., given two monomials first compare the order of $Y_n$, and then $Y_{n-1}$, and finally $X$. In this case the example given above should be false. Am I correct?

Wikipedia gives two references, *A Survey of Transcendentally Transcendental Functions* by Lee A. Rubel and *Irresistible Integrals* by George Boros and Victor Moll. Both of their proofs are quite similar to wikipedia article, but the order they use seems to be more mysterious: they view $X$ as coefficient rather than indeterminate and the order does not involve $X$, so the "highest degree term" is something like $q(X)Y_{0}^{h_{0}}Y_{1}^{h_{1}} \cdots Y_{n}^{h_{n}}$. Then they use some "Euclidean algorithm", which I do not understand how to work for multivariate polynomials. **Should the monomial order involve $X$ or not ?**

Comment: It is possible to view an element $x$ as an indeterminate and a coefficient at the same time. For any commutative ring with unity $A$, there are canonical isomorphisms $A[x, y_0, \cdots, y_n] \cong A[x][y_0, \cdots, y_n] \cong A[x] \otimes_A A[y_0, \cdots, y_n] $. In particular, you can view $x$ as either a coefficient in or a constant freely and in whichever way best benefits the problem at hand.

Comment: @Geoff That is what I am asking: which view benefits this problem. I think the choice is pretty important since it affects the order, and the proof starts with "picking something with smallest order possible".

Comment: Always interesting...: I noticed that questions that can't be answered from the standard textbook curriculum will not be answered here. - And if they can, they often reply with a comment like "see textbook TB". Maybe this website has lost it's purpose.